# regex for validate URL without http/https

Tags: regex, validation, url

All,

I am new to REGEX world...

I know that there are lot of regex avail for validating the common URL with *http* in it.

But I am looking for a regex to validate the URL in the following formats(without HTTP/HTTPS):

- www.example.com/user/login
- www.example.com
- www.exmaple.co.xx
- www.example.com/user?id=234&name=fname

in case if the URL contains only,

- **www.example(without the domain - .com  OR .co.xx)**
- **example.com (without "www")**

I should throw an error to the user.

any help would be highly appreciated...

Thanks
Raj

Comment: Are you only checking one domain? In you example, it would be "example". Or do you want the regex to work with any domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will pass your first set, but not match the second set:

```
^www\.example\.(com|co.xx)(/.*)?$
```

In English, this regex requires:

- starts with `www.example.`
- followed by either `com` or `co.xx`
- optionally followed by `/` then anything

You could be more prescriptive about what can follow the optional slash by replacing `(/.*)` with `(/(user|buy|sell)\?.*)` etc